# Using completionhandler from function variable in NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest issue

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsurlconnection, completionhandler

I have a function :

```
func connectHTTP(requests: String, completion:(NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) -> Void) {

    (...)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(httpRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler: completion)

}
```

If I call `connectHTTP` like this :

```
connectHTTP(requests, completion: {
            (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            NSLog(response)
})
```

the compiler outputs an error :

> Cannot invoke 'connectHTTP' with an argument list of type '(String, completion: (NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) ->
>   Void)'

Does someone know why?

---

Seems like the error message was simply erroneous and pointed to an error inside the closure.

Comment: There is something wrong in your sample code. Should password: be there?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the original code was slightly more complex and I made some errors while simplifying it.

Comment: Note that if I remove `NSLog(response)` the error disappears

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way of passing the closure is like this:

```
connectHTTP(requests) {
    (response, data, error) in
    NSLog(response)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now the error is *Cannot invoke 'connectHTTP' with an argument list of type '(String, completion: (_, _, _) -> _)'*